# What's the name of this binding type where the pages of a book are bound at different locations?

Tags: word-request

In the book shown below, the pages are bound at five different locations:

[image]

What's the name of this binding type where the pages of a book are bound at different locations?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey it's a word/adjective request

Comment: But it needs a bookbinding expert to answer it (as someone kindly has done).

Comment: Most native English speakers will not know a word for this, I suspect!

Comment: @stangdon true. Most native English speakers don't know most English words.

Comment: @KateBunting I've just learned the word but I'm still not a bookbinding expert.

Comment: I didn't suggest that you were; I meant that you should ask a bookbinder, not an English language forum.

Answer (score 21):

The individual folded 'chunks' are, in UK bindery terms, just called 'sections'. Each section is sewn with thread to hold it together, then in a more commercial binding form the whole set of sections glued to a backing strip - the spine - then the front & back pages glued to the inside faces of the book cover. This is known as case binding.

Your example is a rather artisan binding & I can't tell how it's held into the overall cover.  Sometimes this type of book is cross-sewn, each section lightly tacked to the next so they form a loose but coherent unit. This can again be actually sewn to the leather. I can't see enough detail to do more than guess.

Notes for possible confusion of terms.
It appears the US calls these sections 'signatures' - a term I have never heard, though I used to actually work in a bindery making books.
People often think that the sewn edge should be called 'stitched', however, in binding terms 'stitched' is what the man in the street would call 'stapled', like a newspaper or magazine, using a thin metal wire.
If it uses thread, it's sewn.

The decision on section size/no of pages is, of course, made long before ink hits paper. Each of those sections will be made from a single printed sheet, folded then cut three sides to leave the final page layout for each, before being sewn.
There's quite a complex bit of layout math goes into this process - which page backs which & which way up it goes, so they end up in the right order; how much each page needs to move from its perfect centre, depending on how many sheets from the centre-fold it will be, otherwise each thicker fold will change how the margins centre on the final page & you'd see them getting close the the middle line, then away again [amusing, but not a good look;). This is known as 'folding, shingling, or creep compensation'.

The organisation of this print/fold layout used to have some esoteric terms reminiscent of Shakespeare; quarto, folio etc, but certainly in the UK these have been replaced by the far more mundane 8-up, 16-up, 20-up etc, simply stating the number of single-face pages per sheet. This is then said to be 'work and turn' or 'work and tumble' depending on how the reverse is laid out. All the common page layouts have long been calculated, and of course, are now all computerised. I imagine these days there may also be presses than can print sheets double-sided. In my day, only web-fed [continuous roll] presses for newspapers could do that. Everything else was one side at a time, through the press twice.

Comment: As I’ve seen it used, the term _signature_ is not related to the binding specifically, but to the entire printing and binding process as a whole; it’s roughly equivalent to how the term is used in music. If a job is printed and bound as 16-up, then it has a signature of 16 (or a signature of 16-up, I’ve seen both). The end result is the same: a signature of 16 equals 16-page sections, but whereas a section is a physical item, the signature is a property of a print/bind job. I’ve not seen ‘signature’ used as a _synonym_ of ‘section’ before (but I don’t work in the US either).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I really couldn't say. I'd literally never heard the term used in binding until I read the other answer. I've done books as both printer-op [offset litho operator] & prior to that, factory floor bindery; I worked guillotine mainly., occasionally section sewing or perfect binding. I never worked in pagination/layout/separations/plates etc, so maybe the art department used it but we didn't.

Comment: I'm British, and I _have_ heard the term "signature" for what you call a "section" (despite not being close to the binding industry).  It might be age related - I'm in my 60's.

Comment: I'm a fair bit younger than @MartinBonnersupportsMonica but also UK-based and also familiar with "signature" (and I'm also not involved in binding professionally)

Comment: I'm US-based, and have definitely heard them called signatures, but never sections.

Answer (score 4):

Reddit user [spanktruck](https://www.reddit.com/user/spanktruck) [pointed](https://redd.it/11ozfxv) me to the word *signature*:

> Based on the machinery (or lack thereof) used, the publisher will figure out how many pages can be stitched at a single time without something breaking. This group of pages is called a **signature**.
>
> The book is then bound by dividing the page count into signatures. [Certain sizes of signatures are much more common.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_working) Each individual signature is then sewn into the spine; the methods vary. If you mean a specific *kind* of signature-based binding, [this page provides you with some photos of different types of binding.](https://bambra.com.au/news/10-book-binding-methods-you-need-to-know/) If you mean this sort of binding very specifically, probably section sewn.
>
> By contrast, paperback books aren't actually bound: they are just glued in.

Comment: This is too wide of the mark, sorry. Each section is not stitched, it is **sewn**. [Stitching, to a bindery, is what the man in the street would call *stapled*.] Sections are then glued into the spine [case bound], not sewn. Signature must be a US term. In the UK they're simply called 'sections'.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. Thanks for the clarification!